# htaccess redirection hacked urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Recently my website been hacked. In google console is showing urls like: "/Contact?k=63b17fbd214ae34c31b01864c58a701e&c=b-pandora-charm-june" and "/About?k=dacab93a777b7c305b172b9f4f945c58&c=meaning-pandora-elephant-charm"
I would like to redirect any url that contains "k" and "c" parameters to 404 or home page without executing these parameters.
Any help please
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)k=.*&c= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, when the url contain one request like "/?k=request-value-comes-here" is not redirecting to 404 page, Thanks

Comment: Change `RewriteRule` only for `k` with: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)k=.+ [NC]`